# Adding IntelliJ shortcut for tab switcher doesn't replicate default behavior

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, hotkeys

The default IntelliJ shortcut on Mac for switching between a MRU list of tabs is <kbd>⌃ control</kbd>+<kbd>⇥ tab</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> again while still holding <kbd>⌃ control</kbd> navigates to the next item on the list, and upon releasing <kbd>⌃ control</kbd>, the highlighted item is automatically selected, closing the switcher dialog.

When I add <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to the keymap for Switcher, I can activate it using that shortcut, but releasing <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> doesn't close the dialog or automatically select the highlighted item. It must be selected manually using <kbd>return</kbd>.

Does anyone know if it's possible to make a custom shortcut for the tab switcher that behaves the same as the default shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible at the moment:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177432.